# error with copy constructor and getter (mutator function)

Tags: c++, class, oop, exc-bad-access, copy-constructor

so I created a class called WordFrequency that stores a string word and an int frequency as the private member variables.
A HashTable function that contains a WordFrequency** , hashsize , currentitems in the hashtable.

while using the copy constructor i am always getting an error - 
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
that redirects me to the getter function of the WordFrequency class when called in the copy constructor.
i am not able to figure out why is it happening.

the copy constructor.

```
Hashtable:: Hashtable(const Hashtable &hash){

    WordFrequency** temp = new WordFrequency* [hash.hashSize];
     this->arr = temp;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < hash.hashSize ; i++) {
        if (hash.arr[i] == NULL){  //pointer in hashstable is null
            continue;
        }
        //bucket is not empty
        if(this->search(this->arr[i]->getWord())   != 0  ){   //if same string already found in this hashtable
            this->arr[i]->increment();    // incrtement the frequency
            continue;
        }

        //else the string doest even exist in the hashtable.

        WordFrequency x ((hash.arr[i])->getWord());   //deep copying the word from the parameter hash
        temp[i] = &x;                               //pointing the hash table to the new the object

    }
    this->hashSize = hash.hashSize;
    this->currentItems = hash.currentItems;
}
```

the getter function in the wordfrequency class.

```
string WordFrequency:: getWord()  const {
    return this->word;
}
```

although the getter function seems very simple I don't know why am I getting this error.

i am also including my destructor cause that can be the problem.

```
Hashtable::  ~Hashtable() {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < this->hashSize ; i++){
        delete this->arr[i];
    }
   delete  [] this->arr;
    this->hashSize = 0;
    this->currentItems = 0;

}
```

output operator -

```
ostream&  operator<< (ostream &out, const Hashtable &h){
    out << "Hashtable with  size - " << h.hashSize  << "and no of elements - " << h.currentItems << endl;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < h.hashSize ; i++){
        if (h.arr[i] == NULL){
            out << "0";
            continue;
        }
        else {
            out << ((h.arr[i])->getWord());   //bad access
        }
    }


    out << endl;
    return out;

}
```

Comment: Use std::vector<WordFrequency>!

Comment: _" i am always getting an error - Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS"_ OK, and I'm sure your environment will let you run a debugger and see the exact stack trace that leads to that error, with function argument values, so that you can realise why your access is bad.

Comment: I presume the use of a custom hash table is required by the assignment? If not you can save yourself a lot of trouble with `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop of the HashTable constructor, you are storing the pointer of a stack-allocated object:

```
WordFrequency x ((hash.arr[i])->getWord());
temp[i] = &x;
```

That memory gets reclaimed outside of the scope of the for loop, which is causing the "bad access" when you try to access that object later. You should new the object instead:

```
temp[i] = new WordFrequency((hash.arr[i])->getWord());
```

Comment: now my output operator gives me a bad access. can u plz have a look.

Comment: And on exactly which line of code does your debugger tell you the error is occurring?

Comment: @AryanArora Well one thing I'm noticing is that you're not initializing your pointers to NULL when you do `WordFrequency** temp = new WordFrequency* [hash.hashSize];`. So when you do the `if (hash.arr[i] == NULL){  //pointer in hashstable is null` that pointer in the newly allocated array is not initialized.